# Why did Safari drop support for SharedWorker?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, web-worker

Why did Safari drop support for SharedWorker?

And are there any working polyfills using, for example, localStorage and StorageEvent as a communication port? (Yes, the shim would have to detect and recreate the master Worker)

Comment: ["Shared workers can not communicate across processes currently, so they should better be disabled"](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116359)

Comment: I looked through that commit, and I still can't see a sensible reason for why this was dropped... other than laziness on Apple's part in implementing it properly. Chrome seems to have implemented this differently. Shame the fork isn't being looked at by Apple.

Comment: Someone from Apple will add a clarifying comment - in an alternate universe..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly from one of the WebKit Engineers:

> The implementation of Shared Web Workers was imposing undesirable
>   constraints on the engine. It never gained any adoption.

Source [here](https://twitter.com/xeenon/status/652573047623323648)

Comment: Several years later: the WebKit team has [shown renewed interest](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149850#c5) in SharedWorker and [appears to be actively working on implementing SharedWorker again](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230382).

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any polyfills for SharedWorker.

It seems that one can be created by implementing a StorageEvent based communication port across workers. The downside being that StorageEvents are not portable for WebWorkers, and you have to maintain state across each browser tab and know when to flick on/off each master worker.

Comment: You can also use a `MessageChannel`, with the tabs discovering each other through a `ServiceWorker`

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the answers here are correct, but it's also due to the lack of `SharedWorker` adoption by web developers (a chicken and egg type situation).

If you're in need of a polyfill, you can use the one I created. I couldn't find one for one of my projects, so I created this one, https://sharedworker.okikio.dev/.

> **Note**: it doesn't handle cross tab communication, but you can use the [CacheStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) together with a `ServiceWorker` and `MessageChannel` or use `IndexedDB` and `ServiceWorker` (from @jakearchibald on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1389513086047072256)) to create a similar effect

> **Also**: I should mention that Safari is working on supporting the [BroadcastChannel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API), which would cover the cross tab communication aspect, it's currently available in the [Webkit Technology Preview](https://webkit.org/blog/11975/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-133/#:%7E:text=Implemented%20top%2Dorigin%20and%20frame%2Dorigin%20partitioning%20for%20BroadcastChannel)

Answer (score -5):

Since safari default's behaviour on cookies is preventing third-party cookies on tracking.

If safari allows us to use `SharedWorker`, developer(google or tracking company) can use it to access identify between different window tab.

That's the reason why safari drop the `SharedWorker`, interestingly, it support `WebWorker` but not `SharedWorker`.

---

*It's my guess, not the official reason.*

Comment: No. Same-origin policy still applies to shared workers. See stuartd's link: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116359

Comment: Maybe they meant ITP